# adding CSS styles to apex:inputcheckbox

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

I am trying to achieve a simple thing but somehow not able to get the desired result, may be due to my amateur CSS skills.

I have an apex:inputcheckbox and all I want is, when someone selects this checkbox, the CSS of accompanying should change i.e., just to show this one is highlighted. Just want to make it bold and different colour. 
Here is my sample:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem > 
            <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!Dept2}" label="">Elektron
                <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!getSomething}" rerender="working" />     
            </apex:inputCheckbox>   
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

The inputcheckbox is a subsection in pageBlockSectionItem. There are 10 items for the user to select and I want to highlight which one he has selected. When I display "Elektron" in the label, it doesn't show you up on the screen.

The function getSomething is an apex page-reference function and displays result in another PageBlockSection depending upon user selection

It doesn't matter if we use jquery or not, although I believe this can be achieved without query.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a CSS question, not a Salesforce question. I would suggest searching for "checkbox css selectors" or something similar.

Comment: Hi Mike, I did came across some checkbox CSS selectors option, but those apply to plain old HTML <input> tag. I tried to implement the same but to no success. My question is for visualforce tags, specifically to apex:inputcheckbox tag. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to do this with only CSS and you are using a browser which supports the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) and the CSS3 pseudo-classes (`:checked`), you can implement it like this targeting the `label` element immediately following a checked checkbox `input`:

```
<style>
    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
        background-color: yellow;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
```

Key to this implementation is that the `label` element *must* follow the `input` checkbox in the rendered markup and share the same parent element or this CSS rule will not match and the CSS will not be applied.

You will need to inspect your rendered `pageBlockSectionItem` markup to determine if this approach will work for you based on the way that the checkboxes are rendered to the browser.

**Update**

Since there isn't a label immediately following the `inputCheckbox` when using this `pageBlockSection` VF markup (it renders as a table with the checkbox and the label in different table cells):

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Section Title">
    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
        <apex:inputCheckbox id="theCheckbox" value="{!checkboxValue}"/>
        <apex:outputLabel for="theCheckbox" value="Checkbox Label Text" />
    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

one easy way to accommodate this generated markup is to use a jQuery function to manipulate the CSS class on the label on change of the checkbox.

```
<apex:page>
    <style>
        .boldHighlight {
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        // on document ready
        jQuery(function($){
            // target every checkbox in the page
            $('input:checkbox').change(function(){
                // get a reference to the checkbox
                var $checkboxElement = $(this);

                // find the label for the checkbox and toggle the 'boldHighlight'
                // on it based on the state of the checkbox
                $('label[for="' + $checkboxElement.attr('name') + '"]')
                    .toggleClass('boldHighlight', $checkboxElement.is(':checked'));
            });
        });
    </script>

    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Section Title">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="theCheckbox" value="{!checkboxValue}"/>
                <apex:outputLabel for="theCheckbox" value="Checkbox Label Text" />
            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hi Mark, after inspecting my markup, I found out that there is not label tag generated, it's just input tag and plain simple text. I tried to assign a label tag for the input tag, but that didn't work either.

Comment: HI Mike, thanks for the answer, works exactly like I want it, just need to adjust the CSS according to my needs. If you are ever in Germany, the beer is on me.

Answer (score 0):

The Apex tag `<apex:inputcheckbox>` renders as `<input type="checkbox">` so you should be able to just use CSS.

Example:

CSS:

```
.myCheckBox:checked { color: #000; }
.myCheckBox:checked { color: #F00; }
```

Visualforce:

```
<apex:inputcheckbox styleClass="myCheckBox">
```

Comment: HI Mike, thanks for the reply. I had already tried a similar solution before and I also tried your solution, but it did not work.